# Why is my custom constraintValidator throwing null pointer?

Tags: java, spring-mvc

I'm creating a custom `ConstraintValidator` to validate that my JodaTime object's hours are within a certain window when entered from a spring form.

My annotation:

```
@Target({ElementType.METHOD, ElementType.FIELD})
@Documented
@Constraint(validatedBy = InputHoursValidator.class)
@Retention(RetentionPolicy.RUNTIME)
public @interface InputHoursConstraint {
String message() default "";

Class<?>[] groups() default {};

Class<? extends Payload>[] payload() default {};

}
```

My Validator

```
public class InputHoursValidator implements ConstraintValidator<InputHoursConstraint, DateTime> {
private static final DateTimeFormatter HOURS_TIME_FORMAT = DateTimeFormat.forPattern("hh:mma");
private static final String EARLIEST_START_TIME = "5:00pm";
private static final String LATEST_END_TIME = "4:00am";

@Override
public void initialize(InputHoursConstraint constraintAnnotation) {

}

@Override
public boolean isValid(DateTime value, ConstraintValidatorContext context) {
    return !value.isBefore(DateTime.parse(EARLIEST_START_TIME, HOURS_TIME_FORMAT))
            && !value.isAfter(DateTime.parse(LATEST_END_TIME, HOURS_TIME_FORMAT).plusDays(1));

}


}
```

And my mojo with the annotation

```
public class HoursTrackingForm {

@NotNull(message = "Please enter a valid time in AM or PM")
@DateTimeFormat(pattern = "hh:mma")
@InputHoursConstraint(message = "Start time was before 5:00pm or after 4:00am")
private DateTime startTime;

@NotNull(message = "Please enter a valid time in AM or PM")
@DateTimeFormat(pattern = "hh:mma")
@InputHoursConstraint(message = "End time was before 5:00pm or after 4:00am")
private DateTime endTime;

//getters and setters
}
```

It all looks fine to me but when I submit my object for validation,  DateTime in the validator is always null.

Comment: Could not find anything wrong with the code. It should work perfectly fine. Instead the logic for validation itself seems wrong and will always return false.

Comment: @S.K. Logic aside every time I submit a request from my spring form I get back null in DateTime. This wasn't happening prior to adding this custom constraint.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

My issues were two fold.

1) if I was testing a null scenario I didn't realize all of the constraints still get validated even if one finds an error. Therefore while not null caused an validation error my custom constraint would still throw an NPE. Solution for that was to remove the `@NotNull` and do that check as well in `@InputHoursConstraint`.

2) In my validation annotation I added `ElementType.TYPE` and `ElementType.LOCAL_VARIABLE` in `@Target` which appears to allow it to work. Still doing research into why because based on my understanding I only needed `ElementType.FIELD`

Comment: ElementType.TYPE was all that was needed for the class level annotation

Comment: Usually it is a good default behavior of the framework to evaluate all of the constraints even if one finds an error. That way one can offer all violations information at once, e.g. telling the user about ALL existing probems at one when evaluating his/her input. The particular case of custom validations has the risks, that one misses to check if the object under validation may be null. Such null objects might result in Null Pointer Exceptions which of course should be avoided during helpful evaluations. Any Exception thrown might be a bad idea during evaluation, cause it prevents correction.